# Correct way to install scikit-learn on OS-X using port

Tags: macos, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I'm tying to install scikit-learn using port on OS-X. Any idea what I'm missing here.

port version

```
Version: 2.1.3
```

OS-X

```
10.8.2 Build 12C60
```

Xcode

```
Version 3.2.5 (1760)
```

Python

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

command to install scikit-learn

```
sudo port install py27-scikit-learn
--->  Computing dependencies for py27-scikit-learn
--->  Cleaning py27-scikit-learn
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
```

However, looks like it's not installed or configured properly. What am I missing here ?

```
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn
>>> from sklearn import cluster, covariance, manifold
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn
>>>
```

Comment: I am not sure how tied to port you are, but when 10.8 came out I couldn't really rely on it anymore, and the switch to brew was very pleasant.

Comment: also Xcode 3.2 on osx can't be supported, do you need to do an xcode-switch to 4.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved to Homebrew and everything after that was easy.